# Redirect Fabric output to a file

Tags: python, fabric

I use fabric.api.local directly in my script. For example,

fabric_test.py

```
from fabric.api import local

local('echo hello world')
local('ls')
```

If I execute it without any io redirection, everything is fine

```
$ python fabric_test.py
[localhost] local: echo hello world
hello world
[localhost] local: ls
fabric_test.py  test.log
```

If I execute it and redirect the output to a file, the order of the output is messed up.
Why? This problem is really annoying when I use fabric in some cronjob and send the output to logfiles.

```
$ python fabric_test.py > test.log
$ cat test.log
hello world
fabric_test.py
test.log
[localhost] local: echo hello world
[localhost] local: ls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, fabric essentially executes your designated task as a separate subprocess. Hence, the subprocess' output isn't the fabric file's output. This is not a new issue and has been discussed [before](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/57), please check it out to see workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what's going on. I ended up adding '-u' argument when executing the script to force flush on stdout.

Comment: @RyanYe You mean `-u USER, --user=USER  username to use when connecting to remote hosts` ?